# Old icons on /help/formatting

Tags: bug, help-center

I notice some icons are old on https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Screenshots of help center page:

> [image]

> [image]

Screenshot of current tooltip icons on 2023-04-16:

> [image]

Would someone update these to the current icons, please? I prepare icon data for this: [image] [image]

(Background of these icons are white rather than transparent intentionally as a quick workaround for dark mode.)